# In mongodb is indexing an ongoing activity or do we need a cron?

Tags: mongodb

Sorry if the question is stupid.
I'm new to the whole indexing of database and would like to know if I issued the command below

```
> db.posts.ensureIndex({location:"2d"})
```

will the database be always indexed, even when new entries are posted? or do i need to enter this command after every new entry?

Also does indexing make a lot of difference for a database of 2000+ entries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once an index is in place, it will always be used for any subsequent reads and writes. You do not need to keep executing the command.

Keep in mind that issuing an `ensureIndex` on an existing large data set will cause it to index everything that is there immediately, and can block.

There is a whole official FAQ on indexing advise here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexing+Advice+and+FAQ
You should create indexes that match the kind of queries you are doing. Also, its very easy to use `explain` and see how long queries take. When you see you are doing a specific kind of query over and over, you can properly index it to improve performance.

> MongoDB includes an explain command for determining how your queries
>   are being processed and, in particular, whether they're using an
>   index. explain can be used from of the drivers and also from the
>   shell:
>
> `db.comments.find({ tags : 'mongodb'}).sort({ created_at : -1
>   }).explain();`
>   This will return lots of useful information, including
>   the number of items scanned, the time the query takes to process in
>   milliseconds, which indexes the query optimizer tried, and the index
>   ultimately used.

Comment: Hi jdi, thanks for the answer, its much clearer now. Another thing i would like to know is possible to change the index. I mean to remove one property and index another one.

Comment: Yes. There is a command to drop and index. And then you just create a new one. Its all in the docs: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes#Indexes-DroppingIndexes

Answer (score 1):

> or do i need to enter this command after every new entry?

No. Indexes are updated when entries in the DB are updated.

> Also does indexing make a lot of difference for a database of 2000+ entries?

It's not easy to say. It depends what queries you're running and how much of the data MongoDB has in memory.

If your query ends up loading most of the 2000 entries, then the index may not do much. If your query loads only one entry, then the index is probably useful.

Answer (score 1):

Indexing in MongoDB works much like indexing in other relational database servers (SQLServer, MySQL, etc.) and come with their same pros and cons:

- Indexes can speed up reads significantly
- Indexes can slow down writes somewhat (the write has to both update data and the btree holding index information)

If you application is read-heavy, you will see marked improvement in DB response times with proper indexes in place. Follow [the 10Gen Indexing link](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexing+Advice+and+FAQ) that jdi put in his post - it's a great starting point.